# Nested loading route not bubbling

Tags: ember.js

I created a JSBIN to illustrate the issue:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/lodufimufo/1/edit?html,js,output

I can transition from `dashboard/page1` to `dashboard/page2` and `dashboard/loading` is correctly rendered.

But transitioning from `dashboard/projects/1` to `dashboard/projects/2` doesn't render the parent loading template.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this by adding another loading template. To keep your code DRY you could use a partial or component in both templates. So, basically you have to add:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="dashboard/projects/loading">
    Loading...
</script>
```

[Demo on JS Bin.](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ceyujimafo/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I currently do in my app as a workaround. But my question is more of why the behavior described in the docs doesn't work. Maybe I misunderstood the docs or something.. Because I'm trying to do away with adding a lot of these loading templates when ember docs say it would check the parent route if there's no loading route for the current route.

Comment: Maybe this will help you if you try to insert some debug information there - https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.13.3/packages/ember-routing/lib/system/router.js#L737